# C# App is not working after published, why?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

I create, build and publish the app in i7 intel, Windows 7 Ultimate, VS2010 Ultimate.
In this machine the app running up to use the code. In another Machine does not work, why. Thanks in advance, ocaccy.

```
if(!Directory.Exists("C:\\users"))
{
DirectoryInfo di=Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\users");
}

IniFile ini=new IniFile("C:\\users\\monitoring_config.ini");

Error Message on created machine:
************** Exception text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Local MonitorX.CommPort.Open()
   Local MonitorX.Monitor.checkConfigINI()
   Local MonitorX.Monitor.btn_Preferences_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   Local System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)..........................................................
```

Comment: it seems like error is associated with `MonitorX.CommPort.Open()`

Comment: And it would help to see all the code that pertains to the method as well as the error show how `MonitorX` is defined, just curious if you are writing C# why are you using IniFile this can be done but why not use the built in configuration files that .net framework provides..?System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `Means you are trying to use and or Assign a value to an Object that you have not properly created a `new` Instance of

Comment: Thank you.
Is very large; may be by e-amil?

Comment: In pc that was create and published the app; the problem is over. The CommPort was null! Now Install this app in another W7 pc, but does not run, why?

Comment: I discovered that part of problem is allowed to write to the folder C:\Users. Change the code to write in another place and running.

Comment: It is bad practice to write into the "C:\Users\" folder that way. Look for the All Users Application Data folder instead: `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not allowed to write in C:\ or C:\Users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file you are pointing at is missing. If not may an entry of the file is missing.

Hope i could help you a little